# how to run html fast in blackberry widget sdk

Tags: javascript, html, blackberry, widget

i am new in blackberry development world. and i have task to develop the application with blackberry widget sdk.

I have developed the blackberry application with widget sdk. which is fully coded in html and java script. the problem is with the html loading the application. my application is taking so much time to load the html content in the phone device.

And in the device the page taking so much time to load the html and java script content.

So please help me to load the html and java script content fast in my blackberry device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML itself is not the problem. It's rare for HTML to weigh more then 30kB. Instead try to minimize your requests (less images, use sprites, less javascript/css files), and also try to see whether your server (the host of which you grab the information [html, css, javascript] from.).

Good luck ;)

Comment: Rikudo Thanks for reply fast. But my blackberry is running fast in the blackberry simulator but it is the main problem in device. it take long time to load, and the hole project size is min 3.4 mgb. so what can i do for it.

Comment: In which case you could try minifying your JS, CSS and HTML, it could reduce a lot of weight. also, make sure you don't have many loops on your javascript, as it might create stress on the client.

Comment: Also, note that the simulators always run much faster than real devices, so that is not a good stick to measure by.

Answer (score 0):

Try following some of the best practices listed here.
It should improve loading. Minifying js and reducing HTTP requests helps greatly.

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/